# PushPlugin not working on Android 4.0.4

Tags: android, cordova

i have downloaded PushPlugin from https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin and have setup a phone gap project as per instructions in Read Me.

When i run the project on Samsung S2 and Samsung Grand, the device gets registered and a registration id is displayed. however on Samsung Galaxy Duos no registrationId is returned. 
Unable to resolve this issue.

I am using android sdk 17 and cordova 2.9 in my project.

Comment: same problem no solution so far. any progress on this issue ? @simran

Comment: Any one found any solution? - @motto

Comment: @Ajoy yeah turns out using latest version of phonegap solves the problem.

Comment: @motto I am using the latest version of Cordova. But my problem is a bit different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27077173/pushplugin-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-exec Have you seen anything similar?