# PushPlugin TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method ''exec

Tags: cordova, push-notification, phonegap-pushplugin

**Background**

1. I installed [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin). According to the docs I used automatic installation. But when I run `cordova run android`, JavaScript returns the error, 'Cannot read property pushNotification of undefined'
2. If I add

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="PushNotification.js"></script>
   ```

   then the error changes to the one in this question's title.
3. This is how my HTML loads the scripts

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

   <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/model.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/router.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/view.js"></script>
   ```

   Initialization code is in `index.js` where after `deviceready` I call `pushNotification.register`.

   After the `register` completes, I call `MyEmberApp.deferReadiness()`
4. After automatically installing the plugin, I just have to run `register`, according to the docs. But this still leads to 'Cannot read `pushNotification`....'
5. It seems that `PushNotification.js` is automatically inserted after `deviceready` fires. But the plugin is not doing so. If I insert the script in `index.html`, the error `Object has no method 'exec'` occurs because `deviceready` hasn't fired yet.
6. `deviceready`

   ```
   if ('device is android') {
       document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady(), false);
   }
   ```

**Question**

What am I doing wrong? How should I do this?

**Update**

I just realized that I have only tried the automatic installation. I have not tried the manual steps. But that is no reason why the direct plugin install shouldn't work

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it arose as a result of an error in my setup. The question is hence irrelevant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally realized that the error was due to the `EventListener` for `deviceready`. I changed

```
  if ('device is android') {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady(), false);
  }
```

to

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", this.onDeviceReady, false);
```

and everything fell right into place. Though this is a careless mistake, I still leave this question and it's answers for others who might encounter this issue

Answer (score 1):

I can't really see, why ur solution is not working. The only thing I can provide is my working solution. There might be some redundancies or unnecessary things in there, because I myself tried 35 Versions before I got it working:

First Thing is I attach to pg events in an App Initializer and register my Notification Services:

```
Ember.Application.initializer({
    name: 'phonegap',

    /* ...... */

    initialize: function(container, application){
        // Push
        container.register('notification:manager', GambifyApp.NotificationManager, { singleton: true });
        container.register('notification:handler', GambifyApp.NotificationHandler, { instantiate: false });
        container.injection('notification:handler', 'appController', 'controller:application');
        container.injection('notification:handler', 'commentRoute', 'route:usergroup.comment');
    }
}
```

Then my Manager Service is registering the the device:

```
GambifyApp.NotificationManager = window.GambifyApp.NotificationManager = Ember.Object.extend({
    init: function(){
        //var self = this;
        var pushNotification = Ember.get(window, 'plugins.pushNotification');
        if(!Ember.isEmpty(pushNotification)){
            if ( device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android' )
            {
                pushNotification.register(
                    this.successHandler,
                    this.errorHandler, {
                        "senderID":GambifyApp.config.android_sender_id,
                        "ecb":"window.GambifyApp.NotificationHandler.onNotificationGCM"
                    });
            }
        } else {
            Ember.Logger.error('pushNotification Plugin not running');
        }
        GambifyApp.NotificationHandler.manager = this;
    },

    successHandler: function (result) { },

    errorHandler: function (error) {
        Ember.Logger.error('Error while registering with push:' + error);
    },
});
```

Then in a case of success the ECB is called with the device ID which is could by my handler:

```
GambifyApp.NotificationHandler =  window.GambifyApp.NotificationHandler = {

    manager: null,

    onNotificationGCM: function(e){
        console.log('---------- GCM Event:-----------');
        console.log(e);

        if(e.event === "registered") {
            console.log(e.regid); // Registraion ID
        }
    },

};
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Before I try a different approach, I tried to install Cordova Device plugin, but that too did not work.

Comment: It seems that the way I have initialized and used Ember is probably the cause. I'm working on that

Comment: I have tried everything, removed platform, added platform, removed plugins, added them. I also removed all ember code with just the plugins and still the error did not change

Comment: I have updated my question. You might be able to point me in the right direction now!

Comment: Have u tried building the App with build.phonegap.com maybe its a version issue or something